# JHipster - generator give 'Unexpected token' error?

Tags: yeoman, jhipster, yo

Trying to generate a clean jhipster project on a linux mint env

```
yo jhipster
```

gives

```
/home/poc/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/app/index.js:15
    constructor: function (...args) { // eslint-disable-line object-shorthand
                           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.defineProperty.get [as jhipster:app] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:40:23)
    at Store.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/store.js:64:35)
    at Environment.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:262:16)
```

My

```
yo doctor
```

gives

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
```

I'm running these versions

```
nodejs - v4.2.6
npm    - 3.5.2
yo     - 1.8.5
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your NodeJS is too old, JHipster 4 requires 6.9.5, please upgrade node.

Comment: I found the instructions on how to upgrade nodejs here http://askubuntu.com/questions/695138/how-to-upgrade-install-newest-version-of-nodejs-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Your answer is right and it help me too but you should write it on add comment instate of in answer

Comment: For me, upgrading node only not works. I had to update npm version too to solve the error. My current node version is 10.15.3 and npm version is 6.9.1-next.0